# Chrome Browser 32.0.1700.76 is not working with Selenium Webdriver 2.4, what can I do?

Tags: google-chrome, selenium

I am trying to run tests in  Chrome browser 32.0.1700.76 (latest) using Selenium 2 Webdriver  with chromedriver version 2.4
Chrome starts but the string "data;" is displayed in the url bar. 
Those test worked fine with a previous Chrome version (28.xxxxx) but I can't downgrade Chrome.
Can anyone suggest me how can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to either upgrade the ChromeDriver you are using or find a way to downgrade Chrome.

The basic principle of the issue is that the ChromeDriver v2.4's support of the most recent versions of Chrome is non-existent.

You get similar issues with Firefox, an upgrade will sometimes break the tests.

Comment: Using the latest chromedriver (version 2.8) I was able to reuse most of my tests